# Stuck on the splash screen when trying to install elementary

Tags: software-installation

English (Ingles):

I am trying to install Elementary OS, but it is always stuck at first, when I boot the USB (at the elementary logo).

And checked the ISO and tried it several times and nothing, as always.

---

Español (Spanish):

Estoy intentando instalar Elementary OS, pero se queda siempre trabado al principio, cuando arranco la USB en el logo de Elementary.

Ya comprobe el ISO y lo grabe varias veces y nada, lo mismo siempre.

Comment: Hi, in future, please post questions in English as this site uses English and most of the users of the site post in/understand English. For now, I've translated the question for you to the best of my ability. Please note that most of the comments you get will likely be from English-speaking users.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install a dozen times to no avail. ASUS laptop x54c. UNetBootin/USB AND actual DVD burned with K3b. Finally loaded 'liveCD' via USB and installed from desktop icon AFTER successful connection to internet. VioLA! (I love LA)

Comment: I also got stuck, on the Wireless screen. Tried @HOLLYWooDHooP's suggestion and used 'Live' mode and was able to install from there.